# Representing a nested loop in set notation

Tags: notation

I am trying to represent a set of rules using set notation. Each rule has the following format: 
$i.l.T^{i}_{l}$

**This is a small example showing what I would like to represent using    an expression.**

If $S = \{i_{1},i_{2}\}$, $L^{i_{1}} = \{ l_{a}, l_{b} \}$ and $L^{i_{2}} = \{ l_{b}, l_{c} \}$;

$ T^{i}_{l}$ = represents the set of target agents selected with $i$ and $l$ as input

Full set of rules:
$R = \{ (i_{1}. l_{a}.T^{i_{1}}_{l_{a}}),(i_{1}. l_{b}.T^{i_{1}}_{l_{b}}),(i_{2}. l_{b}.T^{i_{2}}_{l_{b}}),(i_{2}. l_{c}.T^{i_{2}}_{l_{c}}), \}$

**Below is the logic for generating the set of rules.**

```
R <- {}
For each i in S:
    L <- get the set of links i can form
    For each l in L(i)
       t <- T(i,l) //Get set of target agents of i under link l
       i.l.T //create this rule
       R.add(i.l.T)
```

**So far I have managed to get this far.**

I am not sure if I have got it right. Especially whether I capture different values of $l$ correctly for each $i$

$R =\{ i.l.T{^i}_{l} |(\forall i \in S) ( \forall l \in L^{i})\}  $

Comment: Why do you need/want to do this? Set vocabulary is probably not the best choice to express the meaning of your code.

Comment: I added the code simply to explain what what the elements in R need to be. Anyway, are you suggesting set vocabulary is not suited for what I try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The following structure may or may not be an answer - since I may not understand your specification.

I think your set $R$ of rules has elements that are ordered triples $(i, l, t)$ where $i$ ranges over $S$, $l$ ranges over a set of "links" that depends on the value of $i$ and $t$ is a "rule" computed from $i$ and $l$ using the function $T$ (unspecified in your pseudocode).

It might be better to think of the rules not as a set but as a function $T$ from pairs $(s,L(s))$ to "rules", where $L(s)$ is the function that computes the "links" available for $s \in S$.

That said, whether an answer to your question is useful will depend on what you plan to do with it. A formal mathematical statement about your "rules" may be necessary if you want to try to *prove* something about them, but may be more confusing than your English or pseudocode if what you want is just a description.